# How do I create a form in Symfony 5 for entity with relations to other entities with have other relations in Symfony way?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, relation, symfony5

Hi all and thanks in advance for any help!
Let's say I have a Symfony **5** App with have entities like:
Hero, Profession, ArmorGroup & Armor and WeaponGroup & Weapon.
The relation between them is like this:

- Single unique **Hero** is a set of one **Profession**, one **Armor** and one
  **Weapon**
- Single unique **Profession** can contain many **Heroes**, many **ArmorGroups** and many **WeaponGroups**
- Single unique **ArmorGroup** is a collection of many **Armors**
- Single unique **WeaponGroup** is a collection of many **Weapons**
- Single unique **Armor** is in a collection of one **ArmorGroups** and is dedicated to one **Profession**
- Single unique **Weapon** is in a collection of one **WeaponGroups** and is dedicated to one **Profession**

Here is a diagram:
[image]

I want to create a **HeroType** form that limits selection of **Armor** and **Weapon** to previously selected **Profession** and show them as a **EntityType** single-choice list with names based on data from **ArmorGroups** for **Armor** and **WeaponGroups** for **Weapon**. All classes have many unique parameters.

Here is my way that is not working:

```
<?php
class HeroType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', NumberType::class, [
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'John Doe'],
            'label' => 'Hero name.',
            'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('profession', EntityType::class, [
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'class' => Profession::class,
            'group_by' => 'affiliation',
            'label' => 'Profession',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('item_armor', EntityType::class, [
            'choice_label' => 'model',
            'class' => ItemArmor::class,
            'group_by' => 'material',
            'label' => 'Armor',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('item_weapon', EntityType::class, [
            'choice_label' => 'model',
            'class' => ItemWeapon::class,
            'group_by' => 'material',
            'label' => 'Weapon',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Hero!']);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Hero::class,
            ''
        ]);
    }
}
```

It can't get property for **'choice_label'** and **'group_by'**. I want to make a form for  **Hero** that fetch data from **ArmorGroups/WeaponGroups** to use as labels, but the values should be **Armor/Weapon** ID's.

**UPDATE:**
This code render the form correctly and as expected:

```
<?php
class HeroType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', NumberType::class, [
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'John Doe'],
            'label' => 'Hero name.',
            'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('profession', EntityType::class, [
            'choice_label' => function ($profession) {
                return $profession->getName();},
            'group_by' => function ($profession) {
                return $profession->getAffiliation();},
            'class' => Profession::class,
            'label' => 'Profession',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('item_armor', EntityType::class, [
            'choice_label' => function ($item_armor) {
                return $item_armor->getIdItemArmor()->getModel();},
            'group_by' => function ($item_armor) {
                return $item_armor->getIdItemArmor()->getMaterial();},
            'class' => ItemArmor::class,
            'label' => 'Armor',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('item_weapon', EntityType::class, [
            'choice_label' => function ($item_weapon) {
                return $item_weapon->getIdItemWeapon()->getModel();},
            'group_by' => function ($item_weapon) {
                return $item_weapon->getIdItemWeapon()->getMaterial();},
            'class' => ItemWeapon::class,
            'label' => 'Weapon',
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Hero!']);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Hero::class,
            ''
        ]);
    }
}
```

But now I get error:

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Profession or null", "instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "profession".

Comment: You may want to use custom queries (group by does not work the way you want it to work, it's not related to the entity): https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

Comment: The choice_label is the field you want to use as label inside your form. I assume something like "name" or "weaponName"?

Comment: Yes, @Nek, You are right. "Model" is basic name. And I believe I won't skip using custom queries. I want to learn Symfony "the correct way" as I saw it in documentation or many tutorials, but sometimes it is necessary to write raw code :) Thank You for answear! Hope someone else maybe have a Symfony-based solution. I try to use EntityRepositories and fetch all possibilities to the form - without success...

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "it can't get property"?

Comment: Hi, I get an error: Can't get a way to read the property "material" in class "App\Entity\Weapon". As this property is from WeaponGroup, not a Weapon Entity itself. They have relation as mentioned above.